# how to save the changes into docker

Tags: django, docker

I currently have this image, that I'm pulling like this

```
docker-compose up -d
```

I'm then running a bunch of django scripts to make the image up-to-date namely `python manage.py migrate` and then `python manage.py createsu` and finally `python manage.py runserver`.

However, each time I'm shutting down the image by doing a `docker-compose down`, all the changes are not applied.

What can I do to save all the changes and to run the same image with the applied changes next time?

Comment: That's what Docker's *supposed* to do, when you start up a new container it's a clean state. If you want to save the state, [`commit`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/) it.

Comment: Docker has an excellent tutorial on [building and running custom images](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/); you'd check a Dockerfile into source control with your application.  Generally you should never use `docker commit`, and you should try to avoid doing extensive work in shells in containers for exactly this reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some talking, I found the way that I feel is the best to me.

```
docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)
```

And to reactivate the image, just do a

```
docker-compose up -d
```

All your changes done in the database will be here.

Answer (score 2):

Let look at my docker-compose file(django):

```
version: "3"
services:
  education:
    image: mysql/mysql-server:5.7
    ports:
      - 3308:3306
    environment:
      - MYSQL_USER=cuong
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=cuong
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=education
    volumes:
      - .:/education/db
  esmweb:
    links:
      - education
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./:/education/
    image: django
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

and Look at volumes. It is as cache. when your code changes, it will change directly.
and When you want to remove data of container, you can do: `docker-compose down`
Hope it can help you.
you can read the documents to know "volumes": [volumes](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/)

Comment: Hi @cuong-daovan, sorry for the lack of precision of my formulation. My aim is to commit all my changes and to be able to use them again, when needed.

Comment: you can use them again, when needed. I will save all the dependencies in volumes that you installed. when you start again, it will not install you dependencies again.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to assume you are using mysql(or other) database *in* the container, instead of on an external volume - if that is the case, you need to not do that.

You will need to either use a database that does not run in your container, i.e. on a separate server, or create a volume that is external to docker image and still run the database software in the image, but using an external volume to store the data.

Comment: Hi @e-j-brennan, thanks but what if I still want to use that container and commit the changes in it...